# Raise an onblur event in lightning:tab

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning-tab

We are creating tabs in a tabset dynamically. We need to save a record when a tab loses focus. For some reason, the onblur event is not raised. onactive works fine, but we already lost the focus of the previous tab.

How can we raise an event before the current tab loses focus?

Comment: please make sure to include the relevant part of the code in your question. thanks

Answer (score 0):

From the description of the problem, and not knowing what your code actually looks like, I can only assume that you're doing something in that tab that you want to save. This means there are other actions you can (probably) listen for within that tab. If you've got a `lightning:input` taking some input, for example, try listening to the onblur event for that field instead.

If you don't have the ability to do that, you might have to fall back on some wrapper  elements with one of these [event listeners](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_eventattributes.asp) attached.